# Hidden Word in list of lists Python

Tags: python, list

I have a function that generates a list of lists from a string of text. I would like it to find a word i.e "noir" within the list of lists, whether by row or column and return the coordinates of that word as:

- `row_start` is the line number for the first letter of the word.
- `column_start` is the column number for the first letter of the word.
- `row_end` is the line number for the last letter of the word.
- `column_end` is the line number for the last letter of the word.

Here is my code so far;

```
def checkio(text, word):
    rows = []
    col = []
    coordinates = [] 
    word = word.lower()
    text = text.lower()
    text = text.replace(" ", "")
    text = text.split("\n")
    for item in text:
        rows.append([item]) #Creates a list of lists by appending each item in brackets to list.
```

example output of above function:

```
   [['hetookhisvorpalswordinhand:'], 
    ['longtimethemanxomefoehesought--'], 
    ['sorestedhebythetumtumtree,'], 
    ['andstoodawhilei**n**thought.'], 
    ['andasinuffishth**o**ughthestood,'], 
    ['thejabberwock,w**i**theyesofflame,'], 
    ['camewhifflingth**r**oughthetulgeywood,'], 
    ['andburbledasitcame!']]
```

In the above case, the coordinates of where "noir" is would be [4, 16, 7, 16].
row start is row #4
column start is column #16 
row end is row #7
and column end is column #16

The word can be found horizontally and vertically, the word cannot be reversed

Comment: it would be helpful if you added an example list and an example output.

Comment: also, can the hidden word occur multiple times in your list of lists, and if yes do you find all of them or only the first?

Comment: If you want row_end, then you are looking for words vertically too? (like in a word search game?)  Can the word be reversed? Is your lists of lists square (though probably doesn't matter)?

Comment: I've added an example list and example output, the word only occurs once in the list and yes I am searching the list of lists vertically as well as horizontally for the word.

Comment: It's not clear what you need exactly, can you elaborate?

Comment: Within the list of lists my function outputs, I need to find a word such as "noir" and return the coordinates of that word in a list by row start, column start, row end, column end. The word can be found horizontally or vertically

Comment: You doing [Bible code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_code)?

Comment: @Malvolio, but then you would want to look backward, upside down... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not completely pretty but answers the question..   :-)  I took the liberty of making this  a list of strings. That will have to be done previously in the code.

```
words = [
    'hetookhisvorpalswordinhand:',
    'longtimethemanxomefoehesought--',
    'sorestedhebythetumtumtree,', 
    'andstoodawhileinthought.',
    'andasinuffishthoughthestood,',
    'thejabberwock,witheyesofflame,', 
    'camewhifflingthroughthetulgeywood,',
    'andburbledasitcame!'
]

word = 'noir'

print [[row+1, line.find(word)+1, row+1, line.find(word)+len(word), line] for row, line in enumerate(words) if line.find( word ) >= 0]

words_transp = [''.join(t) for t in zip(*words)]

print [[line.find(word)+1, col+1, line.find(word)+len(word), col+1, line] for col, line in enumerate( words_transp ) if line.find( word ) >= 0]
```

Output is:

```
[[4, 16, 7, 16, 'sotnoira']]
```

Note, not a lot of error checking.  Exercise for the OP. :-)

BTW, note too, that you will have to be careful with the counting as python starts at 0, hence the "+1"s in there.